# Asyncio Selenium with Chromedriver failes with many threads

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-asyncio

**background**: in order to fetch complex website content I am using the `selenium` package (version 3.141), with the `chromedriver` (version 84.0.4147.89) in `headless` mode, on python (3.8+). To scale up performance the `asyncio` package is used, where `get()` calls are wrapped in a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExcecutor`. Machine is macbook pro 2018, `2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9`.

**problem**: for a small amount of threads, the performance is as expected, i.e. `max=4` threads will load the content of 4 websites simultaneously without problems. However, as the number of threads increases, to say >=8, the timeout ratio drastically increases querying the exact same websites.

**question**: does `selenium/chromedriver` have internal policies that prevent 'true' multiple `webdriver` instances? Or is there something else going on that I don't fully grasp?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but as an alternative if you're looking for another approach to optimisation, consider running your tests in parallel with a combination of zalenium and selenium grid. I've had 8 concurrent chrome tests running in it (with c# not python) with no performance issues... I expect It might take a fair amount of refactoring but have a look here for some more basic info: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/pytest-tutorial-parallel-testing-with-selenium-grid/